# Sum of $\frac{25^x}{25^x+5}$

Tags: summation, fractions

> Find
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{1999}\frac{25^{\frac{n}{2000}}}{25^{\frac{n}{2000}}+5}$$

My work:
$$\frac{25^x}{25^x+5}=\frac{5^{2x}}{5^{2x}+5 }$$

I don't see a pattern here, and I don't think the point of this problem is to evaluate radicals. Please help!

Comment: As a target, *Mathematica* yields $999.5$.

Comment: It may be easier to see what's happening if you replace $2000$ with $4$ everywhere. So that $1999$ becomes $3$.

Comment: With $n=4$ it may be easier to see how a variant of
$$\frac{e^x}{e^x+e^{-x}}+\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=1$$ comes into play.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{25^{x}}{25^{x}+5}.$ Note that$$f(x)+f(1-x)=\dfrac{25^{x}}{25^{x}+5}+\dfrac{25^{1-x}}{25^{1-x}+5}=1.$$
So we have$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{1999}f(\dfrac{n}{2000})&=[f(\frac{1}{2000})+f(\frac{1999}{2000})]+\cdots\\
&+[f(\frac{999}{2000})+f(\frac{1001}{2000})]+f(\frac{1}{2})\\
&=999+\dfrac{1}{2}=999.5.\\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Why does $f(x)+f(1-x)=\dfrac{25^{x}}{25^{x}+5}+\dfrac{25^{1-x}}{25^{1-x}+5}=1$?

Comment: $\frac{25^{1-x}}{25^{1-x}+5}=\frac{25}{25+25^{x}\cdot5}=\frac{5}{25^{x}+5}.$